# print array in specific format

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Items are added to an array, but I need them printing in a speific format.
For example:

`[('Curly',35,'New York')]` printed as:

> Name: Curly Aged: 35 and lives in New York.

Example code:

```
stooges = [('Curly',35,'New York'),('Larry',33,'Pennsylvania'),('Moe',40,'New York')]

print (stooges)
```

Comment: Off Topic?
The problem reflected a genuine problem for a Python 'novice'. I was well explained and was solved within minutes, with some very worthwhile and differing comments added. Surely it reflects everything that is good about this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for stooge in stooges:
    print("Name: {0} Age: {1}, and lives in {2}".format(stooge[0],stooge[1],stooge[2])
```

This uses the [`string.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) function which is really powerful and can do many different types of formatting.

The `{0}` part of the string is used to reference the first parameter to `.format()` and the other two do the same for the second and third parts of `.format()`

Here's a quick example from the docs

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a, b, c'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
stooges = [('Curly',35,'New York'),('Larry',33,'Pennsylvania'),('Moe',40,'New York')]
for t in stooges:
    print('Name: %s Aged: %d and lives in %s' % t)
```

```
Name: Curly Aged: 35 and lives in New York
Name: Larry Aged: 33 and lives in Pennsylvania
Name: Moe Aged: 40 and lives in New York
```

See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: I see what you're getting at here, but it throws up a syntax error on the last inverted comma '

Comment: @JohnCollins I forgot you were using Python 3, try it now.

Comment: print ('Name: %s Age: %d and lives in %s' % t)
Works fine. Thanks

Comment: @JohnCollins No problem. The problem was that in Python 2.x `print` is a statement (so `()` is not required) whereas in Python 3.x `print` is a function.